# How to initialize constant array of generic record in Delphi

Tags: delphi

In Delphi I can initialize a constant array of non generic record like this:

```
type
  TMapEntry = record
    Key: Integer;
    Value: Integer;
  end;

const
  Arr: array[0..0] of TMapEntry = ((Key: 1; Value: 10));
```

But when I try to extent the code in a more generic way then I can't initialize the constant array:

```
type
  TMapEntry<KeyType, ValueType> = record
    Key: KeyType;
    Value: ValueType;
  end;

const
  Arr: array[0..0] of TMapEntry<Integer, Integer> = ((Key: 1; Value: 10)); //<-- Compile error
```

I even tried to use a type alias but got the same compile error:

```
type
  TIntMapEntry = TMapEntry<Integer, Integer>; 

const
  Arr: array[0..0] of TIntMapEntry = ((Key: 1; Value: 10)); //<-- Compile error
```

**Is there any way to initialize a constant array of generic record?**

PS: I am using Delphi 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to initialize a constant array of generic record?

No. Unfortunately this is a limitation of the compiler.

Comment: Thanks @David, if you claim that and didn't come up with a workaround it means there is no way so I accepted your answer as the correct one. But I'm curious:  would not be easy for the compiler to solve this limitation? Could this be reported as a possible compiler improvement for future versions?

Comment: @Delmo I don't know the internals of the compiler. It's worth submitting a QP report, if there is not already one in existence. Then at least there is a record.

Comment: Just to state that "constant of generic record", like
const
  cPair: TPair<byte, byte> = (Key: 1; Value: 1);
is supported